# qt 5 QMediaPlayer error: Gstreamer unable to play

Tags: c++, qt, ubuntu-12.04, gstreamer, qt5

I just installed QT 5 and am trying to run the example for playing video. The code snippet looks like:

```
QMediaPlayer *player = new QMediaPlayer;

player->setMedia( QUrl::fromLocalFile(fileUrl)  );

QVideoWidget *videoWidget = new QVideoWidget;
player->setVideoOutput(videoWidget);

videoWidget->show();
player->play();
```

It compiles fine, but when I run it I get the following error:

```
GStreamer; Unable to play - "file:sample.avi"
```

Im on Ubuntu 12.04 and have installed all of the extra gstreamer packages in case gstreamer was missing codecs. Ive tried with a few different video formats to no avail. I can play the videos using vlc just fine. Does anyone have any idea why this isnt working?

Comment: That "file:sample.avi" looks off, it should be file:// or is it named file:sample.avi?

Comment: The file is called sample.avi. The string "file:sample.avi" is the url that QUrl constructs using the QUrl::fromLocalFile() method after being passed the QString "sample.avi".
Just in case, I tried passing in "//sample.avi" to fromLocalFile but get a similar result. So I dont think this is the problem.

Answer (score 4):

It needs absolute path. Try

```
player->setMedia( QUrl::fromLocalFile(QFileInfo(fileUrl).absoluteFilePath()));
```